# Azure AD Audience / Resource

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am converting my .net core application from using ADFS to AzureAD, I have managed to get it all working but don't understand some of the configuration.

The final error that I resolved was this:

`WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' is invalid"`

If I change my Audience in `startup (AddJwtBearer)` to `00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` it all worked.

The thing is, I have no idea what this identifier relates to, searching through everything in Azure there's no mention of this code.

The closest thing was in the manifest which had a code starting with `00000003`

What is this id relating to?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the error "The audience '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' is invalid"

Scenario: Usually when trying to use the access token with the management.azure.com endpoint, This kind of error message pops up.

Reason for that is it was missing the Resource=https://management.azure.com resource URL

Solution: Add https://management.azure.com  and  add the app registration to the IAM.

Answer (score 1):

`00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is AAD Graph API, if you use it as an audience, then you will get AAD Graph token.

`00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is Microsoft Graph API, if you use it as an audience, then you will get MS Graph token.

Comment: Thanks, this lead me to this article which helped somewhat. https://www.shawntabrizi.com/aad/common-microsoft-resources-azure-active-directory/